# WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) - Input element error - No input on code

Tags: accessibility, opencart-3, wcag2.0

i have a strange problem with WCAG 2.0 (Level AA).
The error below

3.3 Input Assistance: Help users avoid and correct mistakes.

Success Criteria 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions (A)

Check 187: input element has more than one associated label.
Repair: Remove or modify the label elements so there is only one associated label for each form control.
Error Line 1443, Column 1:

```
<body>
    <p name="gl_path" id="gl_path" class="hidden"><span id="thme_path">zemez1029</span></p>
    <di ...()
```

4.1 Compatible: Maximize compatibility with current and future user agents, including assistive technologies.

Success Criteria 4.1.1 Parsing (A)

Check 185: id attribute is not unique.
Repair: Modify the id attribute value so it is unique.
Error Line 165, Column 1:

```
<body>
    <p name="gl_path" id="gl_path" class="hidden"><span id="thme_path">zemez1029</span></p>
    <di ...(search)
```

This is the point where the error appear. There is no input or label and i dont understand whto to do to fix it

```
<body>
    <p id="gl_path" class="hidden">{{ theme_path }}</p>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-preloader" class="visible">
            <div class="preloader">
                <div class="squares">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ie-warning">
            <a href="//windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/{{ theme_path }}/image/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" height="75" width="1170" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <header>
            <div class="top-line">
                {{ header_nav }}
            </div>
            <div class="mid-line">
                {{ header_top }}
            </div>
            {% if navigation %}
                <div id="stuck" class="navigation"><!-- -->
                    <div class="container">
                        {{ navigation }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </header>
```

Comment: do you have the full source code? This does not have a closing body element, so I assume this is an excerpt? It's possible it's marking the first part of the body as the error but the duplicate ID is showing elsewhere. The duplicate ID might also be generated in the header or navigation bits of template

Comment: Yes, it was javascript and product module. They generated dynamically but i fixed the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check 187: input element has more than one associated label. Repair:
>   Remove or modify the label elements so there is only one associated
>   label for each form control. Error Line 1443, Column 1:

There are only two ways I can think of to receive this error.

1. You have two labels with the same `for="itemID"` attribute.
2. You are using the `aria-labelledby` attribute and have pointed that to an `id` that is duplicated on the page.

Your source code may not have these items but the generated HTML almost certainly will.

> Check 185: id attribute is not unique. Repair: Modify the id attribute
>   value so it is unique. Error Line 165, Column 1:

This error is self explanatory, the same `id` is repeated twice within your generated HTML.

**It could be that your accessibility checker is giving you incorrect line numbers and column numbers** so don't rely on those for reference (it tends to happen if you have dynamically loaded content via JavaScript).

Given the first error I would guess that you have an element that has the `aria-labelledby` attribute that is pointing to the `id` that is duplicated causing the second error.

I would also guess that this is being added dynamically via JavaScript for you to not have spotted it sooner so use the `inspect` right-click option to view different items until you find the duplicated `id`. Once you have found it see if the `id` text is repeated 3 times in the DOM (twice for the duplicate ID and once for the `aria-labelledby` attribute.)

So I would expect you to see something along the lines of

```
<div id="a1"></div>
....
<p id="a1"></p>
....
<input aria-labelledby="a1"/>
```

**EDIT**
After thinking about this the most likely cause is either an email sign-up or search box added by your theme.

A search box is the most likely be the culprit as most search boxes do not have labels and your theme is adding a `aria-labelledby` to aid accessibility.

It is likely going wrong because of a plugin for a responsive menu (a mobile menu) as a lot of these plugins duplicate the menu structure and `id`s as they are not well written.

Comment: Hi, i fixed error 187 but i didnt manage to fix the the unique id. If i disable all exetnsions-module the error still exists so i think it is about template only. Search box disabled.

Comment: look at the generated page source via inspector, search for "id=" and look for two identical IDs, then you will know how to fix it. It is normally a menu where this happens.

Comment: I fixed it!! Template uses javascript for search and if you change the php code of search template isnt right! So i change it from admin section.

Comment: great stuff! If my answer helped then please mark it as accepted answer, if not then no worries, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same error (in the same tool you are using) by inserting two `label` for the same element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>ok</title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="input_id">say</label>
<label for="input_id">say</label>
<input id="input_id" value="text" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, you have to remove the second `<label>`

You also have to check that you have not the error "Check 185: id attribute is not unique." which should mean that the same element appears twice and that will cause the same error (187).

This can happen if you have the same plugin in multiple part of your page.

Comment: Fixed! It was module for producr presentation with the same layer id!! Thanks